What Permissions are Needed to Run an Apple API?
I have written this code that access the Apple Core Audio API but every time I run it, it returns a segmentation fault. I am convinced it has something do with the permissions on my device but I am not sure what permissions I need to allow for it to work. If you have any idea of what I can do to fix this, it would be much appreciated.
My Code:
import ctypes
from ctypes import c_uint32, c_void_p, byref, Structure, POINTER, c_int, c_char

# Define constants
kAudioObjectSystemObject = 1
kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal = 1735159650
kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster = 0
kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices = 1684370979
kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceNameCFString = 1819173229

# Define the AudioObjectPropertyAddress structure
class AudioObjectPropertyAddress(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('mSelector', c_uint32),
        ('mScope', c_uint32),
        ('mElement', c_uint32),  
    ]

# Load CoreAudio framework
coreaudio = ctypes.CDLL('/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio')

# OLD PATH: '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio'

# Define function prototypes
coreaudio.AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize.argtypes = [c_uint32, POINTER(AudioObjectPropertyAddress), c_uint32, c_void_p, POINTER(c_uint32)]
coreaudio.AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize.restype = c_int

coreaudio.AudioObjectGetPropertyData.argtypes = [c_uint32, POINTER(AudioObjectPropertyAddress), c_uint32, c_void_p, c_uint32, c_void_p]
coreaudio.AudioObjectGetPropertyData.restype = c_int

def list_audio_devices():
    devices = []

    # Define the property address for getting the list of devices
    property_address = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
        mSelector=kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices,  # Removed .value
        mScope=kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
        mElement=kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
    )
    
    # Get the size of the property data
    property_data_size = c_uint32(0)
    
    status = coreaudio.AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(
        kAudioObjectSystemObject,
        byref(property_address),
        0,
        None,
        byref(property_data_size)
    )
    
    if status != 0:
        raise RuntimeError(f"AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize failed with status {status}")
    
    # Determine the number of devices
    device_count = property_data_size.value // ctypes.sizeof(c_uint32)
    
    # Create an array to hold the device IDs
    device_ids = (c_uint32 * device_count)()
    
    # Get the device IDs
    status = coreaudio.AudioObjectGetPropertyData(
        kAudioObjectSystemObject,
        byref(property_address),
        0,
        None,
        property_data_size.value,
        byref(device_ids)
    )
    
    if status != 0:
        raise RuntimeError(f"AudioObjectGetPropertyData failed with status {status}")
    
    # Get the names of the devices
    for device_id in device_ids:
        property_address.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceNameCFString  # Removed .value
        
        property_data_size = c_uint32(0)
        status = coreaudio.AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(
            device_id,
            byref(property_address),
            0,
            None,
            byref(property_data_size)
        )
        
        if status != 0:
            raise RuntimeError(f"AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize failed for device {device_id} with status {status}")
        
        # Create a buffer for the device name
        device_name = ctypes.create_string_buffer(property_data_size.value)
        status = coreaudio.AudioObjectGetPropertyData(
            device_id,
            byref(property_address),
            0,
            None,
            property_data_size.value,
            byref(device_name)
        )
        
        if status != 0:
            raise RuntimeError(f"AudioObjectGetPropertyData failed for device {device_id} with status {status}")
        
        devices.append({
            'id': device_id,
            'name': device_name.value.decode('utf-8')
        })
    
    return devices

# List all devices and their IDs
devices = list_audio_devices()
for device in devices:
    print(f"Device ID: {device['id']}, Device Name: {device['name']}")

The Error:
zsh: segmentation fault  /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/MYNAME/Desktop/Core_Audio.py
I've tried rewriting the code in a way to accommodate for memory overuse. This codes main goal is to split audio channels Fromm supernate apps so that I can customize each apps volume without changing the whole computers volume.
